# How to extract try catch outside method?

Tags: java, try-catch

I have this method `sendParameterValueAsMQTTMessage()` which I use to publish message via MQTT on a specific topic. I am using try catch two times after another (not nested) but it still seems somewhat ugly and overcrowding the method. I read an article on clean code where Uncle Bob talks about extracting the body of `try catch` but I seem to not grasp it quite well or at least not in my case.

How could I get rid of the `try catch` in my method by extracting it outside?

```
public void sendParameterValueAsMQTTMessage() {
    String payload = null;
    try {
        payload = convertToJSONString("range", String.valueOf(range));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }

    MQTTMessage message = new MQTTMessage(MQTTTopics.RANGE_TOPIC,payload,0);

    try {
        this.client.publish(message);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are multiple different problems with provided code, here is how I'd refactor it:

```
public void sendParameterValueAsMQTTMessage() {
    final String payload = tryGetPayloadAsJson();
    if (payload != null) {
        trySendPayloadViaMQTT(payload);
    }
}

private String tryGetPayloadAsJson() {
    try {
        return convertToJSONString("range", String.valueOf(range));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }

    return null;
}

private void trySendPayloadViaMQTT(final String payload) {
    try {
        final MQTTMessage message = new MQTTMessage(MQTTTopics.RANGE_TOPIC, payload, 0);
        this.client.publish(message);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }
}
```

one thing which might be improved here based on Uncle Bob's advice is to actually move try/catch outside of `trySendPayloadViaMQTT`, like this:

```
public void sendParameterValueAsMQTTMessage() {
    final String payload = tryGetPayloadAsJson();
    if (payload != null) {
        trySendPayloadViaMQTT(payload);
    }
}

private String tryGetPayloadAsJson() {
    try {
        return convertToJSONString("range", String.valueOf(range));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }

    return null;
}

private void trySendPayloadViaMQTT(final String payload) {
    try {
        sendPayloadViaMQTT(payload);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }
}

private void sendPayloadViaMQTT(final String payload) {
    final MQTTMessage message = new MQTTMessage(MQTTTopics.RANGE_TOPIC, payload, 0);
    this.client.publish(message);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put all of your code in just one try block and set multiple catches, when ever an exception be happened, the catch that is revelated to it will be execute, like:

```
try{    
                int a[]=new int[5];    
                a[5]=30/0;    
               }    
               catch(ArithmeticException e)  
                  {  
                   System.out.println("Arithmetic Exception occurs");  
                  }    
               catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)  
                  {  
                   System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception occurs");  
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use single general `catch` for both possible exceptions inside the method as following:

```java
public void sendParameterValueAsMQTTMessage() {
    String payload = null;
    try {
        payload = convertToJSONString("range", String.valueOf(range));

        MQTTMessage message = new MQTTMessage(MQTTTopics.RANGE_TOPIC,payload,0);

        this.client.publish(message);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendParameterValueAsMQTTMessage() {
    String payload = null;
    try {
        payload = convertToJSONString("range", String.valueOf(range));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }

    MQTTMessage message = new MQTTMessage(MQTTTopics.RANGE_TOPIC,payload,0);
  publishMessage(message); //extracted in a new method
}

public void publishMessage(MQTTMessage message){
    try {
        this.client.publish(message);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.logger.log(Level.ERROR, e);
    }
}
```